# What's the differences between ConcurrentSkipListSet and TreeSet in one thread

Tags: java, collections, set

I write the UT as below. Why the size is different with the same compare

```
public void testComparatorRandom2() {
    Random random = new Random();
    class CCC implements Comparator<EventLoad>{
        @Override
            public int compare(EventLoad o1, EventLoad o2) {

        if (o1.getEventId() == o2.getEventId())
            return 0;

        if (o1.getLoad() > o2.getLoad())
            return -1;
        if (o1.getLoad() < o2.getLoad())
            return 1;
        if (o1.getEventId() > o2.getEventId())
            return 1;
        if (o1.getEventId() < o2.getEventId())
            return -1;

        throw new RuntimeException("error");
        }
    }

    Set<EventLoad> eventSet = new TreeSet<EventLoad>(new CCC());
    SortedSet<EventLoad> sortedEventLoads = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<EventLoad>(new CCC());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        EventLoad newEventLoad =  new EventLoad(random.nextInt(RANDOM_NUM), random.nextInt(RANDOM_NUM)) ;
        newEventLoad.setLoad(random.nextInt(RANDOM_NUM));
        eventSet.add(newEventLoad);
        sortedEventLoads.add(newEventLoad);
        System.out.println(eventSet.size()+"=== "+newEventLoad+"======="+sortedEventLoads.size());
        if (eventSet.size() != sortedEventLoads.size())    {
            System.out.println(eventSet.size()+"=== "+eventSet+"======="+sortedEventLoads.size() +"====="+sortedEventLoads);
            //Failed
        }
    }

    AssertResult(sortedEventLoads, eventSet);
}
```

And my equals method is below. Is that correct? Eventid is one attribute of EventLoad.

```
    public boolean equals(Object object) {

    if (this == object)
        return true;

    if (!getClass().isInstance(object))
        return false;

    EventLoad other = (EventLoad) object;
    return _eventId == other._eventId;
}
```

BTW. before add, I can use contains, and the behavior still different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on current research, we found that compare is incorrect, because it not follow A>B &&  B>C then A>C
e.g:

```
A Load 8, Event 10.
B Load 2, Event 8
C Load 1, Event 10;

A>B true;
B>C true;
A>C false 
A=C;
```

That why failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparator is completely broken, so as a result the behavior of all sorted sets is undefined.

(If you ask it to sort a,b and b,a it will not be consistent in saying which comes before which).

Comment: Can you go my new compare to suggestion me how to write the compare, the new compare still have issue.

Comment: Your new compare is a bit ugly but it should be valid. I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code now. Seed the random number generator so it is repeatable and step through in a debugger. Stop it the insert BEFORE the lines go out of synch and look at what is going on.